# Editing navbar text color in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, textcolor

I'm trying to edit the font color of the elements I have in a navabar.I don't want to edit the html font color directly. I want to do it in css. Is this possible? Can i extend the bootstrap class to override the font color they use with my own?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change the color. Try to use the @less or $sass variables to do so:

**Example using less variables:**

```
/
/ Navbar
// -------------------------

@navbarText: #7490BC;
@navbarLinkColor: #FFFFFF;
@navbarLinkColorHover: @white;
@navbarLinkColorActive: @navbarLinkColorHover;
@navbarLinkBackgroundHover: transparent;
@navbarLinkBackgroundActive: @navbarBackground;

@navbarSearchPlaceholderColor: #ccc;
@navbarBrandColor: @navbarLinkColor;
```